# How to save multiple keys with data under single key in firebase or angularFire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

How to save multiple keys with data under single key which is also generated through firebase using firebase or angularFire2?

Please see the example data below.

[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzdwL.png)

Comment: Please explain what you exactly want.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)